# I am attempting to decipher this SQL query I am a bit confused

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
SELECT 'delete schema.'||table_name||' where code =''XYZ'';'||'
commit;' FROM users
```

Here is what I am seeing

```
select delete scheme.table_name where code = 'xyz'; commit; from users
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your confusion is contagious.  Please explain a bit more.  What does the first code sample have to do with the second?

Comment: apologies, on the second line - I am showing the concatenated version of the of the first line. I guess my real confusion lies in "select delete" and as well as the "from users" after the commit without any sort of select, update, insert, delete statement (I am assuming it is a new line since there is a semicolon after the commit). Thanks!

Comment: It's SQL creating SQL, run the select and look at the result. Might be part of a cursor returning lots of DELETEs, which are submitted in a loop. What confuses me is the combination of `table_name` and `users`.

Comment: You are unclear. Please edit your question: What system(s)/layer(s) are you submitting what command(s) to, what is the state and other input, and what is the system/layer action/response? Be clear how text in your message forms a command, state, input or output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see the confusion. But the result should be simple

You arent executing a delete statment you are creating a string

You are using table `user` and there is a field called `table_name`

But your final result is wrong

that is ~ equivalent to

```
select 'delete scheme.table_name where code = 'xyz'; commit;' 
from users
```

What ever the value on `table_name` was

Maybe after the query, you copy/paste the result to your rdbms to execute some commands.

Comment: Thanks! this makes sense! As you mentioned, new SQL is being generated and stored into a file, which is then being executed at another location of the script. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT c FROM t` returns a table with one column named c with a row for each row of table t. An output row contains its input row's column c value.

`SELECT 'pq' FROM t` returns a table with one column and one row. The value for the column is the string formed by a character `p` then a character `q`.

`SELECT 'p''q' FROM t` returns a table with one column and one row. The value for the column is the string formed by a character `p` then an apostrophe character `'` then a character `q`.

`SELECT 'p'||c||'q' from t` returns a table with one column with a row for every row of table t. An output row contains a string that is formed by a character `p` then the characters that form the string representation of its input row's column c value then a character `q`.

> ```
> SELECT 'delete schema.'||table_name||' where code =''XYZ'';'||'commit;' FROM users
> ```

So if you run this query when table users has two rows and the two column table_name values are the strings formed by characters `ab` and by `cd` then the result is a table with with one column and two rows. The values for the one column and two rows are the strings formed by the following characters:

```
delete schema.ab where code ='XYZ';commit;
delete schema.cd where code ='XYZ';commit;
```

If there is only one row in table user and you run your query as a subselect in another query then the one-column one-row table returned by the subselect can be (implicitly) converted to the string that is its one element.

You probably want to pass the (string) value of one such row to the DBMS as a sequence of SQL commands.

But if you are "seeing" the string formed by the characters

> ```
>  select delete scheme.table_name where code = 'xyz'; commit; from users
> ```

then you are doing something else with your query string than running it as a query. But you haven't clearly said what string you are submitting to what system in what state to get what output.